# How to check node permission rules?

Tags: commerce

I'm using drupal commerce and I added a new product (and product display).
I can see it in the listing, but when a user click on the product page, it's saying : permission denied.
All the other products works fine, it's only the last one which doesn't.

I tried to rebuild the permissions but that doesn't changed anything. How can I check what is "denying" the page ?

Comment: Devel module has useful submodule called Devel node access, use that to evaluate your problem further.

Comment: I'm using drupal 7 and `drush` doesn't find a release for it.

Comment: sorry, It was already there. Just needed to enable it.

Comment: Done :) It'd probably be useful if you could comment what was the problem as well in case someone bumps into this issue as well.

Comment: The problem was : someone (me) wrote a node_acces hook to add some custom access rules. I totally forgot about that. I enabled DNA, activate the block by user module and it told me that my own module was denying the access, which was true. I'm in awe about the power of Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module has a submodule called Devel node access, it is really useful to evaluate and track permission problems on nodes. Enable it and place the blocks on a region you're using in your template.